# SQL Server 2005 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Where can I find the SQL Server 2005 Management Studio installation?

Note that I don't want the Express edition.

I just installed the SQL Server and I noticed that the SQL Server Management Studio is not there, did I miss something in the installation ?

Answer (score 3):

It is part of the client / workstation tools selection in the installation package.  Here is a screenshot of the installation wizard.

[image]

Comment: I already select all of these as "Install entire on drive" but couldn't find the management in the start menu

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is installed as part of any edition of SQL Server 2005 except SQL Server Express.  If that is the package you used, either download SQL Express with Adv Services or use the standalone installer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8961

Comment: I uninstalled SQL using the suggested steps in the following link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/50164862-ef20-4758-9c7a-0d6ae8f1b3f9/uninstalling-sql-2005-completely
and then reinstall it using the same package that I used the first time. Now I am able to see the SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

You should download a free SQL SERVER Express Edition, then running the executable you can choose to "add features to existing instance", installing SSMS only.

I usually use this one:

[Link to MS download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1842)

It embeds also Reporting Services and BIDS (if needed).

Comment: Is there 2005 version and not Express?

Comment: My advice is to download the latest stable Sql Server Managemnt Studio (not 2005, at least 2008 R2) as it can attach to any SQL Server instance regardless of version / edition. "Express edition" is related to SQL engine, not SMSS itself.